# Python terminology - class / method / object

Tags: class, object, methods, terminology

I'm new to Python. Just trying to get my head around some terminology. Take the following example:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist.pop(3)
```

Are the following statements correct:

- mylist is an object of the class list
- pop is a method of mylist
- 3 is a variable of the list mylist
- 3 is a variable of the method pop

Comment: That's not a list, that's a tuple. `[1,2,3]` is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `mylist` is an instance of the class (or type) `list`
- `pop` is a method of `mylist`
- `3` is a member of `mylist` or `3` is contained in `mylist`
- `3` is the argument to the method `pop`